# How to Get Nokogiri to Show Node and not just HTML

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Right now when I am parsing some html (front page of hacker news for example), it works fine. I can call class on something like `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('news.ycombinator.com'))` and I will get back `Nokogiri::HTML::Document < Nokogiri::XML::Document`

The issue is, in the terminal, I am seeing the HTML and not the actual Nokogiri Element. I want to see it because it shows me valuable info like the Nokogiri Elements Children, or an array of links or or or.

I get the HTML using the Watir Gem using the following method:

```
[1] pry(main)> browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
#<Watir::Browser:0x2c5654b29ef00c22 url="about:blank" title="">
[2] pry(main)> browser.goto('news.ycombinator.com')
"http://news.ycombinator.com"
[3] pry(main)> browser.html
```

Where browser.html is an instance variable (I think?) containing un-parsed HTML.

Here is what I get back right now if I call `doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)`

[image]

And here is what I would like to get back:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

adding raw code as requested:

```
Nokogiri::HTML::Document < Nokogiri::XML::Document
[31] pry(main)> doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html op="news">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="news.css?stXbi7LCyutClfTUMe1b">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
          <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="rss">
        <title>Hacker News</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><table id="hnmain" width="85%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#f6f6ef">
        <tbody>
<tr><td bgcolor="#ff6600"><table style="padding:2px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr>
<td style="width:18px;padding-right:4px"><a href="https://news.ycombinator.com"><img src="y18.gif" style="border:1px white solid;" width="18" height="18"></a></td>
                  <td style="line-height:12pt; height:10px;"><span class="pagetop"><b class="hnname"><a href="news">Hacker News</a></b>
              <a href="newest">new</a> | <a href="front">past</a> | <a href="newcomments">comments</a> | <a href="ask">ask</a> | <a href="show">show</a> | <a href="jobs">jobs</a> | <a href="submit">submit</a>            </span></td>
<td style="text-align:right;padding-right:4px;"><span class="pagetop">
                              <a href="login?goto=news">login</a>
                          </span></td>
              </tr></tbody></table></td></tr>
<tr id="pagespace" title="" style="height:10px"></tr>
<tr><td>
<table class="itemlist" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tbody>
<tr class="athing" id="19388248">
      <td class="title" valign="top" align="right"><span class="rank">1.</span></td>      <td class="votelinks" valign="top"><center><a id="up_19388248" href="vote?id=19388248&amp;how=up&amp;goto=news"><div class="votearrow" title="upvote"></div></a></center></td>
<td class="title">
<a href="https://www.bennettnotes.com/post/getting-too-absorbed-into-your-side-projects/" class="storylink">Getting Too Absorbed in Your Side Projects</a><span class="sitebit comhead"> (<a href="from?site=bennettnotes.com"><span class="sitestr">bennettnotes.com</span></a>)</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td class="subtext">
        <span class="score" id="score_19388248">42 points</span> by <a href="user?id=_davebennett" class="hnuser">_davebennett</a> <span class="age"><a href="item?id=19388248">1 hour ago</a></span> <span id="unv_19388248"></span> | <a href="hide?id=19388248&amp;goto=news">hide</a> | <a href="item?id=19388248">27 comments</a>              </td>
</tr>
      <tr class="spacer" style="height:5px"></tr>
                <tr class="athing" id="19384878">
      <td class="title" valign="top" align="right"><span class="rank">2.</span></td>      <td class="votelinks" valign="top"><center><a id="up_19384878" href="vote?id=19384878&amp;how=up&amp;goto=news"><div class="votearrow" title="upvote"></div></a></center></td>
<td class="title">
<a href="https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/13/technology/facebook-data-subpoenas.html" class="storylink">Facebook’s Data Deals Are Under Criminal Investigation</a><span class="sitebit comhead"> (<a href="from?site=nytimes.com"><span class="sitestr">nytimes.com</span></a>)</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td class="subtext">
        <span class="score" id="score_19384878">661 points</span> by <a href="user?id=tysone" class="hnuser">tysone</a> <span class="age"><a href="item?id=19384878">13 hours ago</a></span> <span id="unv_19384878"></span> | <a href="hide?id=19384878&amp;goto=news">hide</a> | <a href="item?id=19384878">156 comments</a>              </td>
</tr>
      <tr class="spacer" style="height:5px"></tr>
                <tr class="athing" id="19388091">
      <td class="title" valign="top" align="right"><span class="rank">3.</span></td>      <td class="votelinks" valign="top"><center><a id="up_19388091" href="vote?id=19388091&amp;how=up&amp;goto=news"><div class="votearrow" title="upvote"></div></a></center></td>
<td class="title">
<a href="https://krita.org/en/item/krita-4-2-0-the-first-painting-application-to-bring-hdr-support-to-windows" class="storylink">Krita 4.2.0: First painting application with HDR support on Windows</a><span class="sitebit comhead"> (<a href="from?site=krita.org"><span class="sitestr">krita.org</span></a>)</span>
</td>
...
```

Comment: Please include the code in a code snippet rather than a screenshot

Comment: I cannot provide code for the second image as that is what I am trying to achieve and it is a screengrab from a youtube video. 

That said, happy to add some raw html for the front page of hacker news if that would help.

Comment: Where is `browser.html` initialized? Also, do you have any settings in `.pryrc` or `.nokogirirc` that might affect Nokogiri output?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how `browser.html` was initialized.

I checked `.pryrc` and the only thing I had in it was some code to initialize the awesome_print gem. I do not have a `.nokogirirc` file.

Comment: Maybe `Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html).inspect`?

Comment: @idmean close! I can see that that gives me a single unformatted string, but that the string contains the Nokogiri Node elements. 

Any idea how I would then parse that? And why I have to do that?

Comment: @Rich Why would you want to parse that? This is kind of a XY problem. What is your actual issue? Do you want to access a specific element? Don’t you know about `.css` or `.xpath` or don’t you know how to use them? Have you read the docs, e.g. https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html?

Comment: I don't want to parse that to be honest. I just want to be able to see the Nokogiri::HTML::Document in my terminal so that I can find which element I want to work with without having to open the browser's developer tools each and every time I want to select a new element.

Comment: Work with the raw HTML. Use `curl` or `wget` to download the HTML to your drive and open it with an editor. Don't use the browser's "view source" option because browsers are notorious for rewriting invalid/bad HTML just to allow the user to make some sort of sense from it resulting in you looking for something that isn't really there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML browser.html
```

Comment: I just gave that a try and it gave the same results as `doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse browser.html`


so basically just the raw html.